# Google Bigquery API: How to add result query to Table?

Tags: python, google-bigquery, bigdata

I have already read some introduction about this topic but this code didn't run.
I created table 'product_flat_index' in project and this function add query result to that table. But it didn't run .

```
def insertValues(service):
    project_id = "598330041668"
    dataset_id = 'recommendation_001'
    table_id = 'product_flat_index'


    # [START run_query]

    query = ('SELECT sku, SUM(sales) AS sales, COUNT(sales) AS sales_frequency, SUM(views) AS views,'
          'SUM(carts) AS carts,  SUM(sales) / SUM(carts) AS sales_effective_rate,AVG(rating) AS rating,'
          'SUM(comments) AS comments '
          'FROM recommendation_001.user_input_product '
          'GROUP BY sku '
             )

    configuration = {
        "query": query,

    }
    body = {
        "configuration":
        {
            "query": configuration,
            "destinationTable": {
                "projectId": project_id,
                "datasetId": dataset_id,
                "tableId": table_id
            },
            "createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
            "writeDisposition": "WRITE_APPEND",
        },

    }

    return service.jobs().insert(
        projectId=project_id,
        body=body
    ).execute()
    # [END run_query]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should specify your `destinationTable`, `createDisposition,` and `writeDisposition` properties within your query configuration object, not the top-level configuration.  They are properties of configuration.query, not the top-level configuration.  For example, [here's the `destinationTable` property in our docs: note how it is `configuration.query.destinationTable`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.query.destinationTable), and not `configuration.destinationTable`.  It's structured similarly for the other fields you're specifying.

I think this should work:

```
configuration = {
    "query": query,
    "destinationTable": {
        "projectId": project_id,
        "datasetId": dataset_id,
        "tableId": table_id
    },
    "createDisposition": "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
    "writeDisposition": "WRITE_APPEND"
}
body = {
    "configuration":
    {
        "query": configuration
    }
}
```

---

If you want to debug this on your own, I'd suggest looking up the job details using jobs.list or jobs.get to see if your configuration details made it through to the server.  I suspect your past jobs that didn't work also won't have the additional properties for `destinationTable`, etc.